# publish camera_info and undistort image

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using a node on en jetson nano running melodic, that publish Image topics.
I will calibrate the camera with cameracalibration.py in order to get calibration yaml file.
Then I will need to undistort (rectifie?) the image using data from yaml file.
Is there a package, node, tool that read a yaml file, subscribe to image topic and publish camera_info and undistorted images?

Thank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375637/publish-camera_info-and-undistort-image/) by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2021-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) it should be able to handle exactly your problem.

---

Originally posted by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) with karma: 220 on 2021-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on 2021-04-07**:
ok, that's a middle point becouse it needs a camera_info message.
So, I need a package/node that reads yaml calibration file and publish a camera_info. do you know any?

**Comment by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) on 2021-04-07**:
Unfortunately i don't, but writing a node yourself does not seem to complicated. Take a look at [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/248563/publishing-camerainfo-messages-from-yaml-file/) for reference